# correctly plotting datetime64[ns] to graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

Running into a issue here. See data snapshot below:

Dates:

```
NKE   2019-02-28
NKE   2019-05-31
NKE   2019-08-31
NKE   2019-11-30
NKE   2020-02-29 
Name: asOfDate, dtype: datetime64[ns] symbol
```

Values:

```
 NKE   852000000.00 
 NKE   1737000000.00
 NKE   2023000000.00
 NKE   674000000.00 
 NKE   2165500000.00
Name: FreeCashFlow, dtype: float64 symbol
```

Basically if i were to plot the dates and the values into a bar graph. The value is out of sync with the dates. I've bursting my brains trying to figure this out for the past two hours. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For example:
[image]

See code below:

```
import matplotlib
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Tickers = Ticker('NKE')

cashFlowData = Tickers.cash_flow(frequency='q')

 ax.set_title('Cash Flow Chart')
 ax.set_xlabel('Years')
 ax.set_ylabel('Cash Amount')


 register_matplotlib_converters()

 plt.bar(cashFlowData["asOfDate"],cashFlowData["FreeCashFlow"])
 ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, so it's tough to figure out exactly what you are looking for, but if you are trying to just show the days for the purpose of showing a chart, then you can add the following line of code:

```
cashFlowData['asOfDate']=cashFlowData['asOfDate'].astype(str)
```

Full code:

```
import matplotlib
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Tickers = Ticker('NKE')

cashFlowData = Tickers.cash_flow(frequency='q')
# cashFlowData = cashFlowData[['asOfDate', 'FreeCashFlow']]
cashFlowData['asOfDate']=cashFlowData['asOfDate'].astype(str)

ax.set_title('Cash Flow Chart')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_ylabel('Cash Amount')


register_matplotlib_converters()

plt.bar(cashFlowData["asOfDate"],cashFlowData["FreeCashFlow"])
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
plt.show()
```

[image: By Day for relevant days]

Comment: Hey mate I appreciate your response. I don’t have any issues with getting the data. The issue i am experiencing is plotting the date field from the data.

Comment: @RooseveltH I've edited my answer. It looks like you are plotting daily data over the course of the months, but if you wanted to only show the days you are interested in, then one method could be simply be to convert the date to a string format. Since the date is in a nice format, it would show up in order.

Comment: I really appreciate you @David. This is exactly what I was looking for. Saved me from having a paranoid day trying to figure this out.

Comment: @RooseveltH no problem, after taking a deeper look, I thought that was what you wanted. It is a quick and dirty solution, but if you specifically need to just show the dates AND keep the column with date format, then there are a couple other trickier options.

Comment: it’s all good. I don’t think I want to do anything else with the date column. I really appreciate you mate.